# What is the blobdata txs within the block_complete_entry struct?

Tags: api

In [cryptonote_protocol_defs.h](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/4b2cc123ff48fdd2c62dbffc24c604c45c6fbf1d/src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_defs.h) block_complete_entry is declare that is used within the monero code right?

The block_complete_entry has a blobdata txs.
How does the txs blobdata looks like and what structure does it have?

Bonus question why are tx_output_indices needed within a COMMAND_RPC_GET_BLOCKS_FAST Response. Are the indices not part of the txs blobdata from block_complete_entry ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `txs` field of the `block_comptete_entry` structure is a list of serialized transactions. When you get it from the *getblocks.bin* or *getblocks_by_height.bin* RPCs, it will appear as a serialized array of serialized transactions (i.e. an array of data strings).

A serialized transaction is made of:

- version (varint)
- unlock time (varint)
- inputs (vector of transaction input targets)
- outputs (vector of transaction outputs)
- extra (vector of bytes)
- signature (ring signature if transaction version is 1, and ringct signature if it is 2)

The outputs' indices are not part of the transactions. The daemon builds a table of output indices in chronological order in its database when it processes blocks (c.f. [Where is the global array of outputs of type txout_to_key?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5724/where-is-the-global-array-of-outputs-of-type-txout-to-key)).